# wildfly 25 quickstart ee-security

Tags: security, servlets, wildfly, jakarta-ee-security-api

I can't make the quickstart [ee-security](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/main/ee-security) work with Wildfly 25.0.1.
After sending the request :

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/ee-security/secured -H 'X-Username:quickstartUser' -H 'X-Password:quickstartPwd1!'
```

I get this :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ELY01177: Authorization failed.
        at org.wildfly.security.jakarta.authentication@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.jaspi.impl.JaspiAuthenticationContext$1.handleOne(JaspiAuthenticationContext.java:188)
        at org.wildfly.security.jakarta.authentication@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.jaspi.impl.JaspiAuthenticationContext$1.lambda$handle$0(JaspiAuthenticationContext.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.security.jakarta.authentication@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.jaspi.impl.SecurityActions.doPrivileged(SecurityActions.java:39)
        at org.wildfly.security.jakarta.authentication@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.jaspi.impl.JaspiAuthenticationContext$1.handle(JaspiAuthenticationContext.java:99)
```

What shall I do ?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. The CLI script seems to fail as it's out of date for WildFly 25.0.1.Final. I've creates a JIRA with the workaround https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15671.